# SQL query to get items that have no value for a certain day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a MS SQL Server 2012 table that contains daily reports of people. Each day contains maximum 1 record of a person and the day is stored as a DateTime, having the time part set to  "00:00:00.000". Example: '2014-01-30 00:00:00.000'

```
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+
| Person id | Date                    | Report content |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+
|         1 | 2014-01-29 00:00:00.000 | Account stuff  |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+
|         2 | 2014-01-29 00:00:00.000 | Coaching stuff |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+
|         2 | 2014-01-30 00:00:00.000 | Still coaching |
+-----------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

All personnel are stored in a separate table.

How do I select those people from a database that have missing records for a period? Even if the person reported 30 reports but 1 is missing, he should be in the results. It can happen, that everyone missed one or more report days. This is why I cannot compare people to each other.

For example I would like to know who did not create his/her reports between 1st of January and 1st of February.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Specified the SQL Server version: 2012

Comment: If they don't have a record how you expect to select them? DO you have another table for all the person?

Comment: Do you want a) People who did not submit any report in the period or b) people who did not submit a report every (work?)day in the period?

Comment: I have clarified the question, see my edit. Basically I would like to check if a person has a report for all days in the interval. If not, return him as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK well how about something like

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01 Jan 2014',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '01 Feb 2014'

;WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @StartDate RunDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RunDate + 1
    FROM Dates 
    WHERE RunDate + 1 <= @EndDate
)
, PersonIDs AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            PersonID
    FROM    MyTable
)
, PersonDates AS (
    SELECT  RunDate,
            PersonID
    FROM    Dates,
            PersonIDs
)
SELECT  *
FROM    PersonDates pd LEFT JOIN
        MyTable mt ON pd.RunDate = mt.[Date] AND pd.PersonID = mt.PersonID
WHERE   mt.PersonID IS NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**EDIT:**

Just as a brief over view.

Using a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) structure, I used the recursive nature to generate a list of date.

Then I retrieved a distinct list of `PersonID`s (if you had a `Person` table, that would have helped too, or an active list, or a `MustReportList`, etc).

After that we use a Cartesian product to generate a list of dates by PersonID as to account for all Persons for all dates.

Then we left join onto the original table, and use the IS NULL to determine entries that is missing.

Lastly, the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION)` is to ensure that once you exceed the MAX RECURSION LEVEL, we dont get an exception (basically telling SQL SERVER you know what you are doing).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helped, thank you very much. It would've been nice though to have some explanations, because the code is high level :)

Comment: @Germstorm, added some explenations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
FROM
[Table] A
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM [Table]
WHERE
    [PersonID] = A.[PersonID]
    AND TRY_CAST([Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN TRY_CAST('January 1, 2014' AS DATE) AND TRY_CAST('February 1, 2014' AS DATE)
)
```

Comment: I would prefer the ISO 8601 date format https://xkcd.com/1179/ e.g. BETWEEN '2014-01-01T00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01T00:00:00'

Comment: It depends on the user. The above format is easier to understand and is has one common interpretation. Other formats may cause confusion to users of different zone. dd-mm-yy and other such formats normally confuse users with other formats linke mm-dd-yy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select personid from your_table not in
(
   Select personid from your_table
   Where date between start_date and end_date
 )
```